# Need help with the usage of "ohne zu"

Tags: preposition, conjunction, modal-verb

I'm studying German on my own and I would like some help with this sentence I read in my textbook:

> Deshalb möchte er im Urlaub möglichst viel an der frischen Luft sein, ohne sich zu sehr anstrengen zu müssen.

I get what it means, but there are two things I don't understand:

1. Isn't "*ohne*" just a preposition, shouldn't it be "*ohne dass*"
   in this case?
2. Why is there a "*zu*" in front of "*müssen*"? I thought modal verbs didn't require a "*zu*" to connect with the main verb.

Would it also be correct to say "... *anstrengen müssen*" and would it mean the same?

Comment: Interestingly enough, it's more important for this site to have nicely looking posts instead of directly helping people, anyway because of these edits I looked up ohne zu and my problem is solved, but again with no thanks to any direct answer from anyone, might as well delete this.

Comment: The edit was mainly done to help you with the title. *"Need helm with sentence"* would not have attracted anybody but down or close voters. If you feel unhappy with an edit you can always rollback or further improve your post.

Comment: @user3684 i couldn't answer the question correctly, but i was able to make it easier to read and thus answer, so I did what I could to get you a decent and correct answer. what is wrong with that again??

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't "ohne" just a preposition, shouldn't it be "ohne dass" in this case?

That's still an option: "... ohne, dass er sich zu sehr anstrengen muss." would be perfectly fine. The meaning is somewhat less general than the alternative, though.

> Why is there a "zu" in front of "müssen"?

"ohne zu" + Infinitiv is a very popular and idiomatic construction.

Comment: Achtung: from a logical point of view the "ohne, dass" version means that he doesn't have to make much effort to want to spent time outdoors. The indicative of the müssen-parts makes it seem as if the "ohne, dass" modal adverbial sentence refers to the action of the main sentence (which is also indicative) and that is "möchte"